# How do I shut down remote and local system from terminal?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server

How can I shut down and restart local machine from terminal?

How can I shut down and restart remote systems from terminal. I have remote IP.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Okay thanks next time will take care.. but i thought both should under same command thts why i asked in same

Comment: You generally use different commands to shut down local vs. remote systems, since one needs to establish some communication protocol with remote machines first. Of course, you can access network services on the local machine through the loopback network to shut down the local machine.

Comment: Okay  @DavidFoerster i'll take care next time ... Sorry :) now if you can thn can you please answer if possible than it would be helpful?

Comment: Running the danger of repeating myself, *please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions*.

Comment: @DavidFoerster sorry _next time i'll take care_  and i got the anser

Comment: @user1140237 if you got the answer, please mark it as correct or add it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For remote systems, you can do `ssh <user>@<ip> sudo -c "shutdown -hf now"` for shutdown or `ssh <user>@<ip> sudo -c "shutdown -rf now"` for restart.

For local systems, you can do `sudo shutdown -hf now` for shutdown or `sudo shutdown -rf now` for restart.

Comment: `/bin/bash: shutdown:` command not found

Comment: Sorry, should've added you have to be root. Will update answer

Comment: Is it working better now?

Comment: `Permission denied, please try again.` is it because of my server system is not allowing ?

Comment: Possibly yes. If `ssh <user>@<ip>` gives the same output definately. In that case you should open a new question regarding SSH. The gist of it is, if you want to login as root via SSH you need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow root login.